# Will Brexit potentially have an impact on intra-Schengen flights by EasyJet in November?

Tags: air-travel, schengen, brexit

I need to fly at the end of November between Zurich and Berlin, the price of a EasyJet flight is 150, the flight on Lufthansa or Swiss Air goes for 250. Normally I would just fly with the cheapest option, but EasyJet is a British company and I am afraid they may lose their rights to fly between Schengen space airports in the event of a hard Brexit on 31th of October. I have not found clear information on what could happen and I am afraid the flight may be canceled I could be forced to book a very expensive last minute flight.

Any thoughts on the risk level of buying the tickets with a British flag company?

Comment: It's not clear that Brexit will happen on 31st October, or if it does, what form it will take. Almost any answer will contain some element of speculation. However, easyJet has established a new subsidiary in Vienna ([easyJet Europe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyJet_Europe)) to operate it's European flights. If you book with them you should be OK regardless, but you'd be well advised to check with them direct.

Comment: I don’t think this is opinion based. I think my answer is pretty factual and answers the question.

Comment: This is definitely **not** an opinion but a known fact:   **The EU has agreed measures to allow "basic connectivity" for a year, to prevent planes being grounded the day after a no-deal Brexit.**

Comment: @MarkJohnson that should be an answer.

Comment: @Tim the present answer is the best long term answer. Mayby the quote could be added for the short term. Source was: https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-47225806

Comment: @MarkJohnson yeah I’ll edit that in later. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

easyJet consists of three companies: easyJet UK, easyJet Europe and easyJet Switzerland. You can tell which company is operating each flight [by looking at the flight number](https://www.easyjet.com/en/terms-and-conditions/key-terms):

> When you book your flight with us, your flight booking is issued by easyJet Airline Company Limited. There are three operating airlines in the easyJet group all of which offer the same service on board and throughout your journey. Your flight will normally be operated by:
>
> - easyJet UK Limited if your flight number begins EZY
> - easyJet Europe Airline GmbH if your flight number begins EJU
> - easyJet Switzerland S.A. if your flight number begins EZS

Flights between Zürich and Berlin are operated by easyJet Europe, which is based in Vienna. As The Road Less Travelled noted, this subsidiary was created in order to operate flights within Europe after Brexit. Since easyJet Europe is an Austrian company, it will continue to operate, without any interruption, after Brexit.

Comment: This is correct, but would benefit from pointing out that for 1 year following any no-deal Brexit, EasyJet UK will still be able to operate - so, given the date of this flight, it’s not especially relevant that EasyJet is multiple companies.